# TextView findviewbyID NullpointerException

Tags: android, textview

I really can't find the problem...

I have an onOptionItemSelected.

When calling textView.setText i get a NPE coz findviewbyID isnt working. Any ideas?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_detailview_info, null))
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_ok,
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             //do haxx
         }
     });

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.properties_latest_uploadedby);
textView.setText("NPE");

builder.create();
builder.show();
```

Comment: findViewById finds a view inside of your activity's content. Probably you don't have a textView with properties_latest_uploadedby id.

Comment: check layout.xml of your activity and be sure you hava a TextView with that id declared

Comment: I'm guessing the TextView with id R.id.properties_latest_uploadedby is actually in your R.layout.latest_detailview_info layout file and not in your Activity's main layout file correct? The call to findViewById for that TextView will be looking for the TextView in the main layout and it isn't able to find it and as a result returns null.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below changes.

```
LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_detailview_info, null);

builder.setView(view)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //do haxx
            }
        });

TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.properties_latest_uploadedby);
textView.setText("NPE");

builder.create();
builder.show();
```